# How to programmatically change background color in MS Project 2007 cell?

Tags: c#, ms-project, office-automation

I am tring to automate some MS Project features using C# and cannot find a solution how to change background and font color of special task cell.

I enumerate all tasks in project in that code sample, and when if statemet is true i want to change current cell color

```
foreach(Task t in Project.Tasks)
{
    if(t.Name=="TaskName")
    {
        //I want to change back color of current cell here
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest part is how to select a cell and change color of the cell: `Application.SelectTaskCell` to select a cell [link to MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/office.vbapj.chm2068.aspx) and `Application.ActiveCell.CellColor` to set color of the cell [link to MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/office.vbapj.chm131593.aspx)

But there is a tricky part: `Application.SelectTaskCell` accepts `rowId` as the 1st parameter and there is no way to get row id by any task attribute. So what I did in my test sample:

1. Disable filters by switching to "All Tasks" filter (`Project.TaskFilters` collection)
2. Disable grouping (`Application.GroupApply("No Group")`)
3. Disable AutoFilter (`Application.AutoFilter = False`)
4. Resort everything by ID (`Application.Sort(Key1:="ID", Ascending1:=True)`)

After that Task.ID should be pretty close to Id of the task's row. You can double check what task is selected through `ActiveCell.Task` but that is up to you.

Comment: Thanks a lot and happy new year! You helped me!